# Failed to connect to SQL Server: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-5AHM8D2\SQLNEW in 15000ms

Tags: node.js, express, sql-server-2019

I was using sql server with the same backend code and it was running but I had to upgrade my SSD to I had a new windows installed. With that, I had to install SSMS and SQL server too. I tried connecting like I did before but there was no port available for communication. I opened the SQL Configuration manager but it did not had any option for TCP/IP.
[SQL Configuration manager 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf2xx.png)
I installed multiple instances but same issue. Then I installed SQL Server 2019. After that, tis issue was resolved but now I am unable to connect to sever. I have tried everything I knew and I have searched the internet as well but of no use.
I am using SQL Server 2019 and I am connecting Express to SQL Server but I get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to SQL Server: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-5AHM8D2\SQLNEW in 15000ms
[0]     at C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\fyp\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:85:17
[0]     at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\fyp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:838:9)
[0]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
[0]     at Connection.emit (node:events:514:28)
[0]     at Connection.emit (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\fyp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:959:18)
[0]     at Connection.connectTimeout (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\fyp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1209:10)   
[0]     at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\fyp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1154:12)
[0]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
[0]     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
[0]   code: 'ETIMEOUT',
[0]   originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-5AHM8D2\SQLNEW in 15000ms
[0]       at Connection.connectTimeout (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\fyp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1209:26) 
[0]       at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\fyp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1154:12)        
[0]       at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
[0]       at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
[0]     code: 'ETIMEOUT'
[0]   }
[0] }
```

The following is my connection code:

```
const config = {
  host: "localhost",
  user: "Admin",
  password: "admin123",
  server: "DESKTOP-5AHM8D2\\SQLNEW", 
  database: "fyp", 
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    trustedConnection: true, 
    trustServerCertificate: true
  },
};

// SQL Server connection pool
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const poolConnect = pool.connect();

poolConnect
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to SQL Server");
});
```

All the services in SQL Services are running:

[Services in SQL Server Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaYNi.png)

The shared memory, named pipes and TCP/IP are also enabled and I have checked the PORT for TCP/IP as well but I couldn't resolve this error.

Comment: Which `mysql` node module\version are you using? The `server` property in your config might be redundant and you might need to remove it

Comment: @TBA I q=am using mssql version 10.0.1 and SQL Server Management Studio version 19.2

Comment: SQL Server *10*?! That's SQL Server 2008, and it ran completely of support well mover 4 years ago.

Comment: @ThomA my apologies , the SQL Server 2019 is being used

Comment: In your `package.json` file under dependencies, you should see the mysal package version you're using. Anyway, also try to remove the `server: "DESKTOP-5AHM8D2\\SQLNEW", ` line from your config

Comment: @TBA Did not work